# two submit button one direction

Tags: jquery, ajax, button, submit

I have one `<form id="inputdefect">`,and one `<input id="item">`, but inside that I have two submit buttons:
`<button id="accept">` and `<button id="reject">`

They have same purpose, but different result in the DB. This is the result:

```
item                       condition
tape                       accept
roll                       reject
```

I want if button "accept" is clicked the result at DB is accept.
but if button "reject" is clicked the result is reject.
i have tried to combine both command, but i still confuse to manage command at process page.

```
$("#accept, #reject").click(function(event) {
        if($("#accept, #reject").valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "process1.php",
                        data: "status="+str+"&action=stat",
                        cache: false,
                        async: false,
                        success: function() {
                                  $(".defect").removeAttr("checked");
                                  $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                                  return this;
                        },
                        error: function() {
                                  alert("Data failed to input.");
                        }
                });
                 return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: why buttons be checked if valid?? `$("#accept, #reject").valid()`.. and also serialized??

Comment: @reigel: i have set the radiobutton become required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a bit into the code you posted that sets a hidden input to "accept" or "reject" depending on which one they clicked.